# vector of shared_ptr of abstract class to vector of copys

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I have a vector with shared pointers:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DescriptorsNs::Descriptor> > mDescriptorList;
```

Now i want to have a getter function that returns a vector with copies of those objects:

```
void CatUpdater::getDescriptorList(std::vector<Descriptor*>& descriptorList) const
{
    descriptorList.clear();
    for (auto it = mDescriptorList.begin(); it != mDescriptorList.end(); it++)
    {
        descriptorList.push_back(*it);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that Descriptor is an abstract class and when I try to add them to the vector it correctly states:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h|110|error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘DescriptorsNs::Descriptor’|
```

I can solve this by trying a `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` for all types of derived classes but there should be an easier way of achieving this.

Can anyone tell me a better way of copying the original object to the returned vector ?

Comment: How can you have `std::vector<Descriptor>` if `Descriptor` is abstract? For polymorphism you'd need to have `std::vector<Descriptor*>`

Comment: the vector is like that in the header file, I assign derived objects to it. I'll edit with an example

Comment: Ah this is C++11 so maybe I'm missing something which has changed in the new standard...

Comment: Oh i misread your comment, could be that there is a problem with that too, but the compiler doesn't complain about that yet.

Comment: I don't think C++11 changed that.  You need to use a pointer or reference.

Comment: so is should try and return a list of `std::unique_ptr` probaly. (I can't use raw pointers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make Descriptor object since it is abstract.

But you can make a deep copy of pointers to these objects.

To do that your class Descriptor is missing `clone` virtual method!

Add it to your class and implement properly in your derived.

```
class Descriptor {
 ...
  virtual Descriptor* clone() const = 0;
};


class SomeDescriptor : public Descriptor {
 ...
  virtual Descriptor* clone() const { return new SomeDescriptor (*this); }
};
```

And use clone() while making deep copy of one vector to another:

```
void CatUpdater::getDescriptorList(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DescriptorsNs::Descriptor> >& descriptorList) const
{
    descriptorList.clear();
    descriptorList.reserve(mDescriptorList.size());
    for (auto it = mDescriptorList.begin(); it != mDescriptorList.end(); it++)
    {
        descriptorList.push_back((*it)->clone());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that as you are storing your objects using `shared_ptr`s that either they are large objects and shouldn't be copied around or they represent single instances of something which again shouldn't really be copied.

In this case you might be better just populating a vector of const pointers which would prevent the caller from modifying the pointed-to objects.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<const Descriptor> ConstSharedPtr;

void CatUpdater::getDescriptorList(
                    std::vector<ConstSharedPtr>& descriptorList
                    ) const
{
    descriptorList.clear();

    for (auto it = mDescriptorList.begin(); it != mDescriptorList.end(); it++)
    {
        descriptorList.push_back(it);
    }
}
```

Comment: They can't be made const as the object managing them still needs to be able to change them

Comment: Do you mean, the `CatUpdater` class? That would still hold non-const `shared_ptr`s, it would just be the caller of the `getDescriptorList` who would be given a `vector` of `const shared_ptr`s and would therefore not be able to manipulate them.

Comment: DAMN YOU ! That should probably do what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Thing is, while researching this problem i noticed that shared pointer have quite a bit of overhead in my time-critical application. So I changed my data members to vectors of unique pointers (and so your solution becomes invalid)

Comment: Did you actually analyse performance and find this was the case?

Comment: yes, it wasn't a huge speedup but for an embedded and growing time-critical application every speed boost is usefull

Comment: And now are you doing a deep copy? And that is less intensive?

Comment: Hmmm havn't tested that yet, tested the creation and managing of the objects, not the returning. I'll let you know the results if you wish

Comment: I suppose a lot will depend on the embedded platform but I'd be interested to see which is more efficient, managing shared pointers or performing deep copies.

Comment: Another thing is that i only have to return the copy's once every few seconds, while packets come in at thousands a second, so i don't think the performance loss of the deep copy's will be the issue.